# Equation of motion of ducks from a data set

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, models

I am reading this paper that models the equation of motion of a group of ducks (surf scoters) as observed in Vancouver. The full paper and supplementary information can be downloaded here:

http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2010/06/24/1001763107.DCSupplemental/pnas.201001763SI.pdf

The model is data-driven, and it is easy to understand as it is intuitive.

To summarise, the acceleration of the ducks is a sum of different forces acting on it (environment, social forces, noise), assuming mass is 1.

One of the forces mentioned in the paper is the 'force of alignment' (other forces are repulsion, attraction, etc) and is defined here:

$f_{i,ali} = \dfrac{1}{n_{ali}} \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n_{ali}} \dfrac{v_j}{|v_j|}$

In this case, the velocity of each duck $j$ is two dimensional, and is normalised. The normalised velocities are summed over the number of ducks and averaged.

My question is: How does this illustrate 'alignment' of the ducks?

The other forces (repulsion, attraction) are easy to understand. But I do not see how the ducks are aligned given this force. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The alignment force can be intuitively understood as follows:

The expression for this force averages over the directions of motion of the ducks in the "alignment zone". The result is a net force in the dominant direction of motion, reinforcing this dominant direction.

The net result of this force is to give the ducks all velocity in the same direction, aligning them.